# Rewards of Hall of Monuments

Tags: guild-wars-2, guild-wars

I played Guild Wars (GW1) a long time ago, and I have all the expansions.

Yesterday, I bought Guild Wars 2 (GW2), and linked my two accounts. I went to the Hall of Monuments with my PJ, and I saw that I have a lot more to earn.

So my question is: If I start to play GW2, and install GW1 again, and I get all the items in the hall, will the rewards earned in Hall of Monuments be rewarded in GW2, or once I start to play will I only have the rewards that I have right now?

Here is my Hall's current state:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that you only need 30/50 points in the HoM to get all the possible _rewards_. The remaining 20 points are only worth it if you want to get all the available HoM _titles_ out of it. Many meta achievements in GW2 will give you GW2-specific titles as well; all titles are really good for is bragging rights, so it's up to you whether you consider them important enough to pursue.

Comment: Currently, the Hall of Monuments is bugged and rewards are not appearing in GW2 properly. There's a fix on the way, and HoM rewards will update then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I understood your question.

You can continue to earn rewards towards your Guild Wars 2 account by re-installing Guild Wars and completing Hall of Monuments objectives.

```
Q: Will I be able to continue earning Hall of Monuments rewards in Guild Wars after Guild Wars 2 is released? 
A: Yes.
```

https://hom.guildwars2.com/en/faq/

Comment: Yes! you did :D I found the Q and A in the faq ^^ Thanks! ---> edit if you want your answer with this : is in the faq you give me Q: Will I be able to continue earning `Hall of Monuments rewards in Guild Wars after Guild Wars 2 is released?

A: Yes.`

Comment: Perfect! Happy hunting! I remember not quite finishing the HoM off, landing just short on 49/50 before Guild Wars 2 was released.